# How to keep key name of array when use array_flatten

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Eloquent return value in object and use toArray it's look like

```
array (size=1)
   0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => int 60
      'Name' => string 'ttt' (length=3)
      'Age' => int 444
      'created_at' => string '2013-08-31 13:05:38' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2013-08-31 13:05:38' (length=19)
```

I use array_flatten for solve this but it's replace key name

```
 array (size=5)
 0 => int 60
 1 => string 'ttt' (length=3)
 2 => int 444
 3 => string '2013-08-31 13:05:38' (length=19)
 4 => string '2013-08-31 13:05:38' (length=19)
```

I need to keep key name?

Comment: Why not just access it with `$var[0]`?

Comment: Oop I very very forget it its sorry for poor question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this simple array, you can even 'flatten' it with the following:

```
$result = $arr[0];
```

To flatten a more complex 2-dimensional array use something like this:

```
function nowItIsFlat( $arr ) {
  $output = Array();
  foreach( $arr as $key => $val ) {
    if( is_array( $val ) ) {
      $output = array_merge( $output, $val );
    } else {
      $output[$key] = $val;
    }
  }
  return $output;
}
```

Obviously any duplicate keys will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your array is in `$data`, just use:

```
$data = $data[0];
```